# Generating Points to Line when the points are on either side of the Pacific

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-pro, line, points-to-line

I am currently trying to generate some lines with a dataset that has points on either side of the Pacific ocean. When I try to generate the line, it creates one long line connecting them through the center of the map, as seen here.

[image: as seen here]

I've tried changing the central meridian of the map view, but still end up with this line through the middle. I have a feeling it's something to do with the projection of the points, but I cannot figure out what it is. Unfortunately, I cannot split the dataset into two, as they need to be in one line.

Comment: I think this is a fairly standard problem when a line crosses the 180 degree meridian. You're connecting points with a high positive value to points with a high negative value. For example, -179 degrees to +179 degrees, drawn on a graph, is 358 degrees long. Of course, you want it to "shortcut" across the meridian. If you can use, great circle lines instead.

Comment: identify the pair that straddles the date line, add a vertex on the line,  then make it multipart. It's actually may be easier to split in two, then Dissolve, but a simple UpdateCursor could fix the features *in situ*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For data that crosses the date line I would use PDC Mercator projection which centres on the Pacific Ocean rather than Greenwich meridian.

Comment: This worked!! Thank you, it's exactly the answer I was looking for.